# Error in c++ openCv my very first code (median filter)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, imagefilter

hi I just started c++/openCv and trying to write a median code
i'm cinda confused......

EDIT2:
OK thank to dear friends my first error is corrected
now this is my new error :|
I want to sort 9 elemented Mat file. could I use onother type for **window** not Mat file? how can I sort it corectly

the error refers to this line:
**std::sort(window.begin(), window.end());**
*error: request for member 'begin' in 'window', which is of non-class type 'cv::Mat [9]'|*
*|36|error: request for member 'end' in 'window', which is of non-class type 'cv::Mat [9]'|*

I exped matlab and i'm a complete noob at c++, this is my code:

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
Mat img_gray,img;

int main ()
{

img = imread( "6.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR ); // Load an image
if( img.empty() )
    { return -1; }
cvtColor( img, img_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
int M = img.rows;
int N = img.cols;
cvNamedWindow("windows",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("windows",img);
for (int m = 2; m < M - 1; ++m)
    for (int n = 2; n < N - 1; ++n)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int tmpmedian = 0;
        //int window[9]={0};
        Mat window[9];
        for (int i = m - 1; i < m + 2; ++i){
            for (int j = n - 1; j < n + 2; ++j)
            {
                window[k++] = img_gray.at<uchar>(i, j);
            }
            std::sort(window.begin(), window.end());
            tmpmedian = window[5];
            fimg[m][n] = tmpmedian;
        }
    }
}
```

i'm a student and need this for my class project
and I appreciate your responses thanks alot

Comment: You can access pixel value of Mat variable by using **img.at<uchar>(y, x);**                               Example code :


`Vec3b intensity = img.at<uchar>(y, x);
uchar blue = intensity.val[0];
uchar green = intensity.val[1];
uchar red = intensity.val[2];`

Comment: thanks man this works "img.at<uchar>(y, x);" very well , now I got sort problem and realized that median of a sorted 9 elemented vector is not 5th element! :|

Comment: of course the median of a sorted 9-element vector its 5th element (at index 4 of course). what else should it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your double `for` loop, try this.

```
int k = 0;
int tmpmedian = 0;
int window[9]={0};
for (int i = m - 1; i < m + 2; ++i)
    for (int j = n - 1; j < n + 2; ++j)
        window[k++] = img_gray.at<uchar>(i, j);
std::sort(std::begin(window), std::end(window));
tmpmedian = window[4];
fimg[m][n] = tmpmedian;
```

1. `Mat window[9]` declares an array of 9 `Mat` type object. I don't think you'd want that. You just need an array of 9 `int` values. So what you need is `int window[9]`.
2. Your usage of `std::begin()` and `std::end()` is wrong. `std::sort(std::begin(window), std::end(window))` is what you need.
3. Array indices are zero-based. So your median number is stored at `window[4]` not `window[5]`.